# Putting ternary condition on nested WebGrid result

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, webgrid, razorengine

I have implemented a Nested Webgrid in which I am referring two tables Master Table and Detail Table. I have made Detail table as List type. 
As in the database I am using flags 1 or 0 in certain columns. In my Detail table WebGrid, I need the output 'Yes' for 1 and 'No' for 0. But I am not able to implement the same as it is being declared as List type object.

```
@webGrid.GetHtml(
    htmlAttributes: new { @id = "WebGrid", @class = "Grid" },
                columns: webGrid.Columns(
                webGrid.Column(null, null, format: @<text><img src="~/Images/plus.png" /><div style="display:none"></div></text>),       
                webGrid.Column(header: "Spare Requisition Date", format: (item) => string.Format("{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", item.objSpareRequisition.DATECREATED)),          
                //gridSpare.Column("DATECREATED", "Spare Requisition Date"),
                webGrid.Column(header: "SRS Generation Status", format:  @<text>@Html.Label(item.objSpareRequisition.ISSRSGENERATE == 1 ? "SRS Generated" : "SRS Generation Pending")</text>),
                //gridSpare.Column("City", "City"),
                webGrid.Column(format: (item) =>
                {
                    WebGrid childGrid = new WebGrid(source: item.objSpareRequisitionDetail, canSort: false, canPage: false);
                    return childGrid.GetHtml(
                    htmlAttributes: new { @class = "ChildGrid" },                                                  
                    columns: childGrid.Columns(
                    childGrid.Column("SPAREREQUISITIONID", "Spare Requisition ID"),
                    childGrid.Column("ITEMNAME", "Part Description"),
                    childGrid.Column("QUANTITY", "Quantity"),
                    childGrid.Column(header: "Part Required", format: @<text>@Html.Label(item.objSpareRequisitionDetail.NOTREQUIRED == 1 ? "Not Required" : "Required")</text>),                                                    
                    childGrid.Column(header: "Is Chargeable", format: @<text>@Html.Label(item.objSpareRequisitionDetail.ISCHARGABLE == 1 ? "Yes" : "No")</text>),                                                    
                    childGrid.Column(header: "Is Used From Kit", format: @<text>@Html.Label(item..ISUSEDFROMKIT == 1 ? "Yes" : "No")</text>)                                                    
                    ));
                })
        ))
```

Comment: Is double dot after item a typo in `@Html.Label(item..ISUSEDFROMKIT == 1 ? "Yes" : "No")`?

Comment: Yes its a typo.